# Redirecting output to file then back to console in C++

Tags: c++, file, stdin, freopen

The task is to read input from `input.txt` and write the output to `output.txt`.
However on completion of the above tasks, further instructions/output should now be displayed to the console.

Came to know about freopen() in c++ which works fine for the first half of the given task. But unfortunately, I have no idea how to redirect the output back to the console again.

```
void writeIntoFile(){

   freopen("input.txt","r",stdin); // Task 1. Reading from input.txt file
   freopen("output.txt","w",stdout); // Task 2. Writing to output.txt file
   printf("This sentence is redirected to a file.");
   fclose(stdout);
   printf("This sentence is redirected to console"); // Task 3. Write further output to console

}
```

What I expected from fclose() was that it would end up writing into the text file and would hence further write the output into the console, but it doesn't. How can I achieve task 3 as well.

Comment: Don't use `freopen` or redirection in the first place. If you are writing in C++, use a C++ stream, and just open it normally and then write to it.

Comment: I understand, but in that case I will have to write all output individually like  file>>text;
This can be automated with freopen() and hence I chose this.

Comment: We have different stream objects so that we can use them for maximum readability and correctness. Reopening files all over the place means your code is cryptic and impossible to read.

Comment: Not to mention *"The original stream (if it exists) is closed."* -- which may or may not be intended.

Comment: Maybe rdbuf is what you're looking for? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you are looking for is rdbuf() as mentioned by doomista in the comments.

Here is a way to redirect Output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    /** backup cout buffer and redirect to out.txt **/
    std::ofstream out("out.txt");

    auto *coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());

    std::cout << "This will be redirected to file out.txt" << std::endl;

    /** reset cout buffer **/
    std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);

    std::cout << "This will be printed on console" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```